# Should I have one class with multiple variables and a TYPE variable or a few subclasses?

Tags: object-oriented-design

I am developing a web based vehicle tracking application. Clients buy GPS devices and the company I work for mounts it on their vehicles. The client then gets a user name and a password for the software and this is how he is able to monitor his fleet.

However, when the company started to grow some clients want to mount GPS devices on static plarforms which are not VEHICLES! Other clients want to be able to list all their fleet units inside the software EVEN if they didn't buy a GPS device for them but they simply want to be able input some data which is not tracking related.

So I have to improve the software in order to be able to handle the dummy units and the platforms which locations do not change.

So here comes my question:

Should i have few classes like:

**Vehicle**(id, maxSpeed, Canbus, FuelTankCalibration, AnalogSonda, GpsDevice.....)

**StaticPlatform**(id, Location, AnalogSonda, GpsDevice....)

**DummyVehicle**(id, MetaData,.....)

***or one big class***

**FleetUnit**(***Type***, id, maxSpeed, canBus, FuelCalibration, AnalogSonda, GpsDevice, Location, MetaData,.....)

and based on the **Type(VEHICLE, STATIC_PLATFORM, DUMMY_VEHICLE)** variable to handle the various situations?

Comment: You should have the arrangement that most effectively models your problem domain.

Comment: Robert Harvey is correct. However, most people would use a base class for the common portion of the vehicle/platform, and derived classes for each specific type. Do whatever results in the least and simplest code.

Answer (score 3):

In order to understand which of these approaches have merit for your domain, you need to understand how these entities are going to be used.  Which is to say ***you need to express some requirements***.

Many focus on [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) implementation, which is great; however, I prefer to look ***first*** at the  abstractions and domain concepts being offered to the consuming client programmer (often you).  So, I would look at the needs and usage scenarios of the consuming clients first, to make sure the abstractions and domain concepts you're creating here are easy to manipulate, hard to get wrong, and accomplish the jobs consumers are interested in doing.

It is not clear whether the first option you're suggesting refers to "wholly independent separate classes", or "inheritance from common (abstract) base class".

The "wholly independent separate classes" approach, is simple; however it is contraindicated if you end up duplicating methods between the two classes.  Here I am paying particular attention to the interfaces, because for a consuming client, using different classes that offer a common subset of methods yet do not share an interface or base class, are a pain to consume.  (Their implementations are also likely not DRY.)

The "one big class", is also pretty simple.  Here one code smell is if you find clients using a switch statement on the "type" field and special casing the different "types"; by using inheritance along with tell-don't-ask, such can be cleaned up.  Still, if you don't have this code smell, then this is an appropriate solution.  Another code smell can be inapplicable attributes for certain types of entities, i.e. where you might have to pass or provide "null" in construction, or some other value that indicates "missing and not applicable".

However, even with a notion of a StaticPlatform, a GPS reported location can make sense; it can be applicable, and, there's no need to null this out.  A StaticPlatform may be moved once in a while even though it isn't a vehicle.  With non-static platforms, a given home location may make sense as well.  So, perhaps a home location and a reported GPS location may make sense for all your types.

Use of inheritance is a bit more complex, and may actually be overkill or YAGNI.  On the other hand, you may have cases where the differentiation/specialization is very useful.

Also, don't forget that you can pick one and refactor if you find a difficulty in using it, or some code smell.  After all this is what make software "soft".